# Set value in array - Prolog

Tags: arrays, recursion, prolog, accumulator

I have some rule which set_value_in_array.
He is repalce value in Array[J] by Val.

```
set_value_in_array([], _, _, _, _).
set_value_in_array([Head | Array], Val, J, AccJ, NewArray) :-
    AccJ = J,
    NewAccJ is AccJ + 1,
    set_value_in_array(Array, Val, J, NewAccJ, [Val  | NewArray])
    ;
    NewAccJ is AccJ + 1,
    set_value_in_array(Array, Val, J, NewAccJ, [Head | NewArray]).

 -----------------------------
 -----------------------------

% execute in terminal
?- set_value_in_array([1,2,3], 10, 1, 0, NewArray).

true ;
true.
```

Why set_value_in_array NOT show NewArray as [1, 10, 3]?
He is always return true.

Update:

When I do 
set_value_in_array([],  Val, J, AccJ, NewArray) :- write(NewArray).
He is return something looks to right solution

```
?- set_value_in_array([1,2,3,4,5,6],100,1,0,X).
[6, 5, 4, 3, 100, 1|_G516]
true.
```

But how to make it work without write function?

Comment: http://pastie.org/2538878 - My simple stupid solution. But it works

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you don't construct the result correctly. It should be the other way round:

```
set_value_in_array([Head | Array], Val, J, AccJ, [Head | NewArray]) :-

    set_value_in_array(Array, Val, J, NewAccJ, NewArray)
```

There are also several other problems with the code.  In general you should think carefully what the smaller cases are when you remove the first element of the list, and what the base case is (ypou don't specify the result list there).

You also need to specify that `AccJ \== J` for the second case.